# Why won't C# show the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express

Hey guys,

Pretty new at C# here. I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson01) C# ADO.NET tutorial (currently on step [2](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson02)), and I'm stumped. I'm following all the steps, and everything makes sense to me in it, but whenever I try to debug, it does not show anything (in the sense of the c# methods not printing out a table from Northwind database onto my webpage) in `WebApplication1`'s Default.aspx page.

For a while, I thought it was my connection string, `conn`, and I wasn't naming the `"Data Source"` attribute, which from my understanding is the name of the server I'm trying to connect to. It is all on a local machine, and I'm putting the correct server name.. I think. Server name is `AZUES-221\JDOESQLSERVER`

I'm properly escaping the backward slash, but I still don't know. Is there something in my coding that's flawed? Please help!

*C# code*

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class SqlConnectionDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Main(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AZUES-221\\JDOESQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=SSPI");

            SqlDataReader rdr = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", conn); //passed the connection

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // get query results

                while (rdr.Read()) //prints out whatever was
                { Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]); }//selected in the table
            }

            finally
            {
                if (rdr != null)// closes
                { rdr.Close(); }// the reader

                if (conn != null)//closes
                { conn.Close(); }// the connection

            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Try using `Debug.WriteLine` instead of `Console.WriteLine`, there is no console attached to a web application.

Comment: No, it's in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, hit Ctrl+. (Ctrl and the Dot-key) after the Debug word and use the popup to add the required using directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your example seems to be a **WebProject** try to put your code within `Page_Load` eventHandler. Afterwards you should try to print your data to the `Debug` window or to a control within your webPage.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
// and all the others ...

namespace WebApplication1
{
  public partial class SqlConnectionDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AZUES-221\\JDOESQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", conn); 
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // get query results

            while (rdr.Read()) //prints out whatever was
            { 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rdr[0]); // or on the other hand
                lblOutput.Text += rdr[0];   // as a "quick and dirty" solution!
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)// closes
            { rdr.Close(); }// the reader
            if (conn != null)//closes
            { conn.Close(); }// the connection
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You may it find very useful to have a look at [databound controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-bound-controls) or just use another type of project (eg winForm, console, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Console application** instead of the Web Application you have created. 
Otherwise you will run into similar issues considering you are new to C# (or Visual Studio in general) AND considering the rest of the tutorial uses Console.WriteLine heavily.

Then you can use the same code as shown in the tutorial.

[image: Console Application from Visual Studio 2008]

Additonally if you are concerned about the slash in the database server (it is a database server instance), you may wanna try this:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=AZUES-221\JDOESQLSERVER;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

Source: [Connection Strings Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

why would console.writeline show anything. you are not working on console.

in case just to see your output. use Response.writeline(rdr[0]);